# Why does org.json.JSONArray implement Iterable<Object>?

Tags: java, org.json

Would it not make more sense to implement `Iterable<JSONObject>`?

With `Iterable<Object>`, I think that a `forEach` would be written:

```
json.forEach(object -> {
    JSONObject objectJson = (JSONObject) object;

    if (objectJson.has("my_key"))
    {
        // ...
    }
});
```

However, with `Iterable<JSONObject>`, a `forEach` could be written:

```
json.forEach(objectJson -> {
    if (objectJson.has("my_key"))
    {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Are there other benefits I do not see to having `JSONArray` implement `Iterable<Object>` rather than `Iterable<JSONObject>`.

Is there a cleaner alternative to the first code snippet above?

Comment: Perhaps you've misunderstood the [JSON format](http://json.org/). An array  can contain elements of any of the JSON types.

Comment: From the `JSONArray` Docs: "Values may be any mix of JSONObjects, other JSONArrays, Strings, Booleans, Integers, Longs, Doubles, null or NULL. Values may not be NaNs, infinities, or of any type not listed here. "

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, you're right - I did not consider any other data type. Do you know a better way to write a `forEach` considering there are so many different types? Wouldn't one have to check the data type, then cast, and then proceed?

Comment: That's right. Don't use the `org.json` API if you can avoid it. Use a more sophisticated API like Jackson or Gson. Note that you'll still need to verify the type of the elements, but it'll be done with cleaner client code (rather than a bunch of `instanceof`).